# Graph - Adjacency List C++ - All Paths from source to destination

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, adjacency-list

I am trying to find all paths from a source node to a destination node in a graph. The graph is directed. I am using a rather simple adjacency list representation for the graph with C++.
This is what I use for the  nodes:

```
struct node
    {
        int id;
        std::vector <int> neighbours;
    };
```

Neighbours are the nodes that you can reach from a node.

This is what I use to store the whole graph:

```
std::vector < node > graph;
```

Example:

[image]

For the graph above, using the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<graph.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout<<graph[i].id<<"->";
        for(int j=0;j<graph[i].neighbours.size();j++)
        {
            std::cout<<graph[i].neighbours[j].id;
            if(j!=graph[i].neighbours.size()-1)
                std::cout<<",";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
```

Gives me all the adjacencies correctly as:

0->1,4,3

1->2

2->3

3->

4->2

Now, I want to write such a function:

```
void find_paths(int start, int end)
```

That when you give the start and ending points, it will print out all possible paths from the start to the end point.

Example: When I run,

find_paths(0,3) :

0->1->2->3

0->4>2>3

0->3

I want such an output. Performance is not really an issue here. Any working algorithm could do. What sort of algorithm can I use to solve such a problem? Also, if there are no possible paths, how can I get the function to recognize this?

Comment: What should happen if your graph contains a cycle somewhere? There might be infinitely many paths. Or should a path be edge/vertex disjoint to be valid? You have the tag "shortest-path", but judging from your sample output, you also want other paths... so *exactly*  what do you want?

Comment: Well, sorry about the misleading tag, I couldn't find or think of any tag that could represent my desire to find all the paths in the graph. What I _exactly_ want right now is **all** the **simple** paths from the source node to the destination node. Meaning that the path should include at most n-1 edges(n being the number of nodes), so in the case of infinitely many paths, those paths shouldn't be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [Depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).
Both methods are designed to traverse the graph, in different orders, to find a certain node.

To get all solutions and not just the shortest one, you could keep a list of all paths which led to success during traversal.

Comment: I implemented Depth First Search and it worked! Thanks for the help. :)